# Histogram with multiple colors for each bar to indicate the different components

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a histograms, and I currently do:

```
plt.hist(y_pred_train_bdt[y_train_==0], color='r', alpha=0.6, range=high_low, bins=bins,
                 histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, label="b1")
plt.hist(y_pred_train_bdt[y_train_==2], color='y', alpha=0.5, range=high_low, bins=bins,
                 histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, label="b2")
plt.hist(y_pred_train_bdt[y_train_==3], color='orange', alpha=0.4, range=high_low, bins=bins,
                 histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, label="b3")
plt.hist(y_pred_train_bdt[y_train_==1], color='b', alpha=0.5, range=high_low, bins=bins,
                 histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, label="s1")
plt.hist(y_pred_train_bdt[y_train_==4], alpha=0.5, range=high_low, bins=bins,
                 histtype='stepfilled', normed=True, label="s2")
```

In reality I want only 2 histograms, the first is the sum of the first 3 histograms "b1" "b2" and "b3" and for the second I want "s1" and "s2". I want the contribution of the 3 components for the first one and 2 components for the second one visible with different colors.

How can I draw a histogram where each bar has multiple colors and the height visualises the contribution of each component?

For example if in bin 1 b1:b2:b3 is 1:2:3 then the bottom 1/6 of the bar should be red, then 2/6 should be yellow and the final 3/6 should be orange.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py

Comment: @caverac that is the idea. How can I have a stacked histogram instead of a stacked bar graph (the x-axis has numeric values that must be binned)?

Comment: Maybe separate the data aggregation from the plotting? First compute your histograms, add them, then plot bar graphs with the computed data.